# query.php - multiple is_category functions

Tags: wp-query, categories

Why does `query.php` have multiple is_category functions?!

E.g. in my version of WordPress (4.x) I have in `query.php`:

```
line 230: function is_category( $category = '' ) {
line 4095:  public function is_category( $category = '' ) {
```

Comment: `is_category()` is just a wrapper function for `$wp_query->is_category()`

Comment: I can see that from the code. What I'm trying to understand is why there are 2 is_category functions in that file - one explicitly public, one not.

Comment: one is a function, the other is a class method. it's purely for convenience.

Comment: Snow Crash, I was going thru PHP documentation and found that both methods are public - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php. I found other duplicate methods in query.php (setup_postdata). Still not clear on why duplicates are provided and why one is more convenient than the other as per @Milo's response.

Comment: @sotn because calling a simple function is easier than calling a class method, which requires you reference the global variable containing the instance of the class, which may or may not need to be globalized before referencing, depending on context.